# sudo apt-get is not working

Tags: 14.04, apt

So I keep trying to run the following command `sudo apt-get install libaa-bin` and every time I get the message. `Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing/` I' ran `sudo apt-get update` but when I try the command again I get the same response. Any help here?

This is my `sources.list` :

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

here's what I get when I run `sudo apt-get update` :

```
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources/DiffIndex                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources/DiffIndex          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources/DiffIndex                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources/DiffIndex           
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources/DiffIndex             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en              
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US         
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_US       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_US   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/anton+/dnscrypt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 146.112.61.106 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/663939/edit) your question to add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: did you try the `--fix-missing`? E.G. - `sudo apt-get install -f libaa-bin`

Comment: can you please explain  how that works I'm still kind of new to Linux @heemayl

Comment: Got the same message @HeatherBrown

Comment: From your `terminal` run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, you would get some output, then [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/663939/edit) your question and copy-paste the output you have got from that command..

Comment: Sent it up now @heemayl

Comment: Ok, now run `sudo apt-get update` and post the full output ..

Comment: so what am I missing on all of the @heemayl

Comment: Please post the full output of `sudo apt-get update` ..

Comment: ok but you may need to edit it once I post it sorry @heemayl

Comment: it's up @heemayl

Comment: For some reason, your IP is being blacklisted (or may be a server side problem)..check after some time or if you want you can temporarily disable the problematic repos by commenting out the relevant lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and also from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and then everything should be normal..also enable those after some time to check again..alternately you can use another mirror that is near to you..

Comment: I think I figured it out, I put opendns on my computer and put really tight restrictions on it so I think it got caught up in DNS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here it appears you might be behind some proxy or your internet is regulated which is blocking your access to some IP addresses.

If the error is because of some proxy/regulation then your best bet is to download the deb file using browser form https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libaa-bin/download (assuming you can acess this website on your network)

and then run the .deb file to install libaa-bin